# Advanced spreadsheet auto-formatting

Tags: microsoft-excel, spreadsheet, openoffice-calc, google-spreadsheets, conditional-formatting

Is it possible to autoformat spreadsheet like this

IF A1 = C1 then A1:E1 cells background becomes light gray

I use OO Calc, but it's ok if you know how to do it in MS Excel or Google spreadsheet

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In OOo as well as in Excel, just combine an absolute reference for the column with a relative reference for the row. This way, you can copy the conditional format to every cell, and it will evaluate the values of cells A and C in the current row.

In OOo, you will have to define the conditional formatting as follows:

1. Select a cell in row 1 that should be conditionally formatted, then select "`Conditional Formatting...`" from the Menu "`Format`";
2. Define the conditional format using the formula `$A1=$C1`. This is valid if you've selected a cell in row 1. If you're defining the format for a cell in row **2**, use `$A`**`2`**`=$C`**`2`**. The **`$`** defines an **absolute reference** that won't change if you copy the format to other cells. If the `$` is missing, the reference is **relative** (it will change on pasting it to another cell). So, if you copy the reference $A1 from the first to the second row, it will point to $A2.
   [image: conditional formatting]
3. Copy the cell, select the other cells that should be conditionally formatted and select Menu "`Edit`" -> "`Paste special`" or <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>SHIFT</kbd>+<kbd>V</kbd>;
4. In the "`Paste Special`" dialogue, in the "`Selection`" options, deselect everything except "`Formats`".
   [image: Paste Special]

As result, the conditional formatting is defined for every cell selected in step 3, whith the formula pointing to cells A and C of the current row.

Answer (score 2):

You should be able to do that with conditional formatting in excel, I'm not sure about the others.  The exact method will depend on the version of excel.

EDIT: This should be what you need I don't have 2007 to test it though

In Excel 2007:
Select range

On the Ribbon, go to the Home tab and click Conditional Formatting

Click New Rule

Click Use a Formula to Determine Which Cells to Format

For the formula, enter
=A1=A3

Click the Format button.

Select a font colour to match the cell colour.

Click OK, click OK

Comment: I have excel 07

Comment: Made mistake in my question it should be if A1=C1, but anyway this way it works only for 1 row, I want that it would work for entire sheet, like if A1=C1 then change colour A1:E1, if A2=C2 then change colour A2:E2 and etc.

Comment: I'm sure that can be done but I'm on a PC without office so I can't test it.  It might be worth doing the first row then using the format pasting option to apply it to the other rows, I think that will sort the cell references out.

Comment: ok, on excel its pretty same like tohuwawohu answered about OO, but anyway thanks for help